# Doubled prefix sub-directory with custom registration controller for Devise when wrong credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Environment:

- ruby 2.3.1p112
- rails (5.0.7)
- devise (4.4.3)

My whole application is in a sub-directory.
Everything is fine, let's say for example if I am in the `/tutu` sub-directory and my `ENV['RELATIVE_PATH']` is set properly, every links and behaviors are fine.
Except for the registration paths (which I had to prefix to prevent misleading URLs with `:users` resources). The registration path is now set to `auth` (please see the configuration setup down below) and is not prefixing the URL properly, like `/auth/users/sign_in` instead of `/tutu/auth/users/sign_in`.

```
# config/route.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope Rails.application.config.relative_url_root || '/' do

    devise_for :users, path_prefix: 'auth', controllers: {
      registrations: 'registrations'
    }
    get '/auth/users', to: redirect('/')
    resources :users

    # having various resources here ...

    root 'pages#index'

  end
end
```

and

```
# config/application.rb

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Life
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.root_directory =
    config.relative_url_root =
    config.action_controller.relative_url_root = ENV['RELATIVE_PATH'] or ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']
    config.assets.prefix = "#{config.root_directory}#{config.assets.prefix}"
  end
end
```

I then temporarly replaced the line:
`devise_for :users, path_prefix: 'auth', controllers: {`
by:
`devise_for :users, path_prefix: "#{Rails.application.config.relative_url_root}/auth", controllers: {`

And the links `new_user_session_path` and `new_user_registration_path` are now leading at the right place, but if I try to sign in with wrong credentials for example, on the returned error page (`signin` page but with some flashes), all the links on the page and forms actions are now set with doubled prefixes as `/tutu/tutu` (only if I go wrong with credentials).

Is there a way to fix this doubled prefix, what am I doing wrong ?
Also, I am interested in having a clean way to add my prefix, without having to use `Rails.application.config.relative_url_root` to the prefix registration paths (if it's possible).

Comment: The application is really simple, I believe the error can easily be produced with only the setup above.

Comment: If I try it in local with only having `'auth'` for `path_prefix` for the registration custom controller, the prefix `/tutu` also got duplicated when trying wrong credentials.